# sending data from one function too another in a different component in another folder

Tags: reactjs

I have state from my LineContent.js which is in a seperate folder. It  contains an onclick from an a component inside the LineContent(  ). I want to grab the same data from the onNodeClick and pass it to a different component in a different folder..Here is what I mean:

Here is my folder structure:

```
LineageContent
--LineageContent.js

ModalBar:
--ModalBar.js
```

The onNodeClick is stored in the lineage content, data is retrieved from lineage content and I want to pass it too modal topBar.

LineageContent.js

```
 const onNodeClick = async (e) => {
    if (lineage.lineageMode === 'SQL') {
      let children = []
      if (e.children) children = e.children.map(c => c.name)
      if (e.__children) children = e.__children.map(c => c)
      let data = {asset_id: e.asset_id, assettitle: e.assettitle, asset_type: e.asset_type, children: children}
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await get(`sqls/${e.asset_id}?refs=${children.join(',')}`, user.user)
      data.sql = results
      postLog('miscellaneous_class,SQL Modal', user.user)
      setShowSqlModal(true)
      setSqlData(data)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    } else if (lineage.lineageMode === 'Drill') {
      const path = `${siteUrl}?asset_id=${e.asset_id}&asset_title=${e.assettitle}&asset_type=${e.asset_type}`
      window.open(path, '_blank').focus()
      postLog('lineage_class,Lineage Vizual', user.user, e.asset_id)
    }
  }

return (

    </div>
          <LineageTree
            id='lineage'
            zoomHeight={lineage.lineageZoom.height}
            zoomWidth={lineage.lineageZoom.width}
            lineageData={lineage.lineageData.lineage}
            mode={lineage.lineageMode}
            nodeClick={onNodeClick}
          />
        </div>

)
```

I have copied and pasted the function to the topModal component, but obviously that does not work as there is no e target. I don't want to have the LineageTree component in the topModal component as it is a shortcut so I was wondering how I could get the e values from the onNodeClick in the lineagecontent file to the topModal component.

```
  const onNodeClick = async (e) => {

    const line = await lineage 
    console.log(line, 'from line');

    assetDetails.onLineageClick('SQL')

    if (lineage.lineageMode === 'SQL') {
      let children = []
      if (e.children) children = e.children.map(c => c.name)
      if (e.__children) children = e.__children.map(c => c)
      let data = {asset_id: e.asset_id, assettitle: e.assettitle, asset_type: e.asset_type, children: children}
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await get(`sqls/${e.asset_id}?refs=${children.join(',')}`, user.user)
      data.sql = results
      postLog('miscellaneous_class,SQL Modal', user.user)
      setShowSqlModal(true)
      setSqlData(data)

      loading.setLoading(false)
    } 
  }

return(
      {!(['EDH Table', 'Report'].includes(assetType) && assetDetails.usageMode !== 'Review') ? null :
          <div>
              <Button text='Get SQL' className='CircleButton ModalTopbarButton' onClick={onNodeClick} />
              <SqlModal showSqlModal={showSqlModal} sqlData={sqlData} onCloseSqlModal={onCloseSqlModal} />
          </div>
          }

)
```

Answer (score 0):

then try to:-

1. import `ModalBar.js` into `LineageContent.js` component:-

- `LineageContent.js`:-

```
import ModalBar from '../whateverpathto/ModalBar'
```

2. Then in `onNodeClick` function, do something like this:-

- `LineageContent.js`

```
const onNodeClick = async(e) => {
  // ... your long if else code

  // return ModalBar component as passing the required states you wanna use in ModalBar component
  return <ModalBar sendWhatEverProps={sendWhateverProps} />
}

return (
  <LineageTree
    id='lineage'
    zoomHeight={lineage.lineageZoom.height}
    zoomWidth={lineage.lineageZoom.width}
    lineageData={lineage.lineageData.lineage}
    mode={lineage.lineageMode}
    nodeClick={onNodeClick}
  />
)
```

3. lastly in `ModalBar.js` (pass `props` as argument)

- 'ModalBar.js'

```
const ModalBar = ({props}) => {
  return (
  <p>{props.whateverBeingPass}</p>
  )
}
```